# requirejs HTML structure

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

I know we could use requirejs combine files into one js file.
such like the following config.

```
module.exports = {
      baseUrl: 'js/',
      mainConfigFile: 'src/js/common.js',
      dir: 'scripts/',
      optimize: 'uglify2',
      modules: [
        {
          name: 'common',
          include: [
              'jquery',

          ]
        }

      ]
    };
```

my result into one file is

```
common.js
----------------
jquery.js
modernizr.js
common.js
```

my question is, do we still need to put a require.js file in `scripts` folder and to use the following format

```
 <script data-main="scripts/common" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

or we could just use

```
 <script src="scripts/common.js"></script>
```

as files are compressed into one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to load `require.js` the usual way to actually make use of the module loading benefits that it provides, and especially if you use the asynchronous functionality a lot. However, you can have a look at [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) providing your code uses AMD and ([from the README](https://github.com/jrburke/almond)):

> - optimize all the modules into one file -- no dynamic code loading.
> - all modules have IDs and dependency arrays in their define() calls -- the RequireJS optimizer will take care of this for you.
> - only have **one** requirejs.config() or require.config() call.
> - do not use [RequireJS multiversion support/contexts](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion).
> - do not use require.toUrl() or require.nameToUrl().
> - do not use [packages/packagePaths config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages). If you need to
>     use packages that have a main property,
>     [volo](https://github.com/volojs/volo) can create an adapter module so
>     that it can work without this config. Use the `amdify add` command to
>     add the dependency to your project.

Almond is great because it doesn't need `require.js` at all; it wraps your own code with itself, which is a very minimal AMD loader skeleton and nowhere near as powerful as the main library. You then get a single optimised file that can be linked directly in your HTML:

```
<script src="scripts/common.js"></script>
```

The Gruntfile config for [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) could look something like this:

```
compile: {
    options: {
        name: 'path/to/almond',
        baseUrl: 'js',
        include: ['main'],
        insertRequire: ['main'],
        mainConfigFile: 'scripts/config.js',
        out: 'scripts/main.js',
        optimizeAllPluginResources: true,
        wrap: true
    }
}
```

The above is all standard r.js boilerplate, you can find many more examples at the almond homepage.